# alert if marker is outside the polygon

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am currently developing a web application that would alert if a systems  generated marker is outside a polygon, but my function is only working in 1 polygon, it does not work in other polygon. Is there something wrong in my loop or what did i miss ?

See image here: [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOe9e.png)

Here is my function.

---

```
function checkInPolygon(marker) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  for (var x = 0; x < mpa_polygon.length; x++) {
    var html = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.getPosition(), mpa_polygon[x]) ? 'inside' : 'outside';
    console.log(mpa_polygon[x]);
  }
  infowindow.setContent(html);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Full code implementation:

```
function displaySalesMan() {
  var names = [];
  var ids = [];
  var dateMPA = [];
  var longlat = [];
  var header = [];
  var loc = [
    []
  ];
  var newdata = [];

  $.ajax({
    url: "/geofencing/GeofencingAPI.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      "type": "view_salesmanDashboard_gensan_COLOR",
      "filter_Date": getDate()
    },
    dataType: "html",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      if (response == 'No records are generated on selected salesman and date!') {
        alert('No records are found in selected date!');
        DeleteMarkers();
      } else {
        console.log(data.length);
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[x].latitude, data[x].longitude),
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|' + data[x].TERRCOLOR.substr(1)
          });

          >
          i call the
          function here with a parameter ** marker **

            checkInPolygon(marker);
          markers.push(marker);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, x) {
            return function() {
              var contentString = "<div style='overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto;'><div class='modal-header' style='text-align: center;'><div class=''><img style='height: 120px; width:120px;' alt='salesmanPic' src='img/jomar.png'></div></div>" +
                "<div class='table-responsive'>" +
                "<table class='table table-condensed'>" +
                "<tr><td>Salesman:</td><td class='bold'>" + data[x].Salesman + "</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Customer:</td><td>" + data[x].Customer + "</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Location:</td><td>" + data[x].longitude + ' ' + data[x].latitude + "</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Delivery Date:</td><td>" + data[x].deliveryDate + "</td></tr>" +
                "</table>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>";
              infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);

            }
          })(marker, x));

        } //end for

      } //else
    } //on succjess
  }) //ajax close tag

  //checkerForSalesman(markers, mpa_polygon);
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;



} //display salesman funciton
```

Comment: Your function works fine ([proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bqajt4wL/).  Why do you think it doesn't work?  What do you mean by it doesn't work in the "else part" of the program?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, along with the error messages you are getting (if any).

Comment: yes it works only in last inserted polygon in the database, it does not work in other polygons :(

Comment: _my function is only working in 1 polygon, it does not work in other polygon_; is `mpa_polygon` just an array with coordinates literals or we have a different data structure here? What is the error you are getting in the console? It would be nice to get a self-contained code sample that would help in reproducing the code, rather than guessing. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood of your code, for each marker you going to ask "is this in first polygon? yes o no" then you insert the answer in the infowindow of that marker...then going to ask for the same marker "is this in the second polygon? yes o no" and so on, always overwriting the previous answer for the previous polygon....that is why it only works for the last polygon inserted.

So the **solution** here would be find a way to keep separate answers for each polygon, or select which polygon are you aiming.

To be clear if a marker which is only one point, can only have 2 posibles states (true or false) and you have 3 polygons..that breaks the equation. cause for instance in the image you provided, all the markers shows good results if your reference is the red polygon...but you need to know which of the 3 polygons you are referring to.

Hope it makes sense

Comment: it makes sense,  i find a way like i put my `infowindow.setContent(html);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);` part inside the loop so that it would not overwrite the previous answer, but it still not working. but i will look forward on making separate answer each polygon thank you for the recommendation (y)

Comment: it now works thank you mo much for your answer :) @betofarina

Comment: you are very welcome, glad it helped you troubleshooting